# scroll parallax using margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

The below works with background-position: but it does not work when trying to use the same effect on a different element using margin-top: the second element does not have a background - but is div with content. Any suggestions?

```
function parallax() {
    setpos(".filter-page");
    setpos(".filter");
//    setpos(".filter", 4);
//    setpos("#pb3");
//    setpos("#pb4");
}

function setpos(element, factor) {
    factor = factor || 2;

    var offset = $(".filter-page").offset();
    var w = $(window);

    var posx = (offset.left - w.scrollLeft()) / factor;
    var posy = (offset.top - w.scrollTop()) / factor;

    $(".filter-page").css('background-position', '10% '+posy+'px');
//    $(".filter").css('background-position', '15% '+posy+'px');

    $(".filter").css('margin-top', '10% '+posy+'px');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    parallax();
}).scroll(function () {
    parallax();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
$(".filter-page").css('background-position', '10% '+posy+'px');
```

it means you're setting the values **x (10%)** and **y(posy pixels)** of the background-position, wich is a valid value to this property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) - because you can set both X and Y at the same time.

However the attribute **margin-top** does not expect this kind of value (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp). There is no way to set X and X values to "margin-top". This attribute has only one value to be setted. So, if you remove both 10% or posy px this will work.

Comment: thanks, however this doesn't increment with the scroll, though? It just changes the margin on page load, but it doesn't trigger nor increment with the vertical scroll as the background-position does

Comment: Take a look at this

https://jsfiddle.net/4qxmaodp/1/

I changed the "scroll" function to "click" to make things easier and created a global variable called "increment". Every time you click in the image this variable increments by 30 and as you can see also the background position and the margin-top.

Maybe you did somenthing incorrect and the margin was not updating,
Well, just check out this code and see if solves your problem

Comment: Thanks but when I change it to scroll function everything spazzes out and breaks

Comment: Check out the link again jsfiddle.net/4qxmaodp/1

I updated the code to increment 1 by 1, now using the scroll function. That code works, what maybe happened is that scroll can trigger multiple times every time you scroll and the old increment value was hight, making it increment a lot more than you expect.. Now i think you can see the difference, check out!

Comment: The only problem with this is, it does not reverse when the user scrolls up.